# Setting up RD session collection

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp

I am setting up a windows server to host remote apps. Its more of a proof of concept project rather than a full production thing and it will only need one user (me).

I have a server pool of 2 computers, one is my domain controller and the other is hosting the connection broker and I would also like it to host the remote session. I am trying to add it to the RD session hosts list however no servers are listed in the pool to pick from in this list. 
Also i am not taking the virtualization route as my hardware does not support it.

Does anyone have any ideas why I cannot add the Server to the Session collection list even though it is included in the pool? Can the same server not be used for the Connection broker and the session collection?

Thanks

Comment: Did you select the Standard Deployment (services are divided across servers) or Quick Start (installs everything on one server) ? If you try to install the deployment again using Add Roles and Features and select a session host, will it work then? Standard Deployment usually doesn't allow you to install more roles on one server using the Overview in Server Manager

Comment: Ok, I did use standard, i will try removing the roles and reinstalling them tonight

Comment: You don't have to remove the connection broker role if you still want standard deployment. Just start the installation again and add a session host. Or simply use the Quick Start. Do note that with the quick start you won't be able to add any further servers to the same deployment.